# Applications not allowed in AppStore

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry

Where can I get a list of application types that aren't allowed in the mobile platform app stores? Eg. IOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone.

For example: adult content not allowed, what others r there?

Comment: can you provide a little bit more info?

Comment: Like porn/adult content apps not allowed, what other types are there?

Comment: There are other things - Apple for example prohibits emulators. Google recently took off Ad-aware for violating the Store ToS. Porn and non-porn aren't the only categories. :)

Comment: Start reading the different stores guidelines...

Comment: that depends on the appstore company, e.g. google's guidelines are much different to apple's or microsoft's. but you can get the info  on their websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here you are, but remember, you can do this by yourself! (Google it!)

1. Google    (Android):
   http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en
2. Apple     (iOS):
   http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf (PDF)
3. Microsoft (Windows Phone):
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

no guarantee that all links work

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe any app store prohibits certain "types" of applications per se. You will have to carefully examine the guidelines of each app store to determine what is allowed and what isn't. Even then - this isn't written in stone. An app might be allowed initially due to oversight, lack of apps etc. and removed later if there is public outcry or the organization responsible for that App store change their mind.

Answer (score 1):

As for Android, please check [this page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en) to read information about application content rating.

Please refrain from non-programming questions next time, SO is a programming resource